# Vertically align two tables of different sizes

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a table with too many columns and I don't want to present it in landscape. So my idea was to cut off some columns and start a new table below. Now I want the upper (longer) table to be centered on the page and the lower one to be left-aligned with the upper one. I have tried to put them both into a centered minipage and within this minipage flush them to the left. But that doesn't seem to work so I don't have a solution.

[image]

Here's my code (sorry for not clearing up the preamble).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\usepackage[colorlinks,
pdfpagelabels,
pdfstartview = FitH,
bookmarksopen = true,
bookmarksnumbered = true,
linkcolor = black,
plainpages = false,
hypertexnames = false,
citecolor = black] {hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,patterns,calc,matrix,arrows.meta}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,56,101}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{106,176,35}
\definecolor{tablegreen}{RGB}{224,239,212}
\definecolor{tableyellow}{RGB}{255,251,204}
\definecolor{tablered}{RGB}{252,212,209}
\usepackage{colortbl,dcolumn}
\def\zz#1{%
\ifdim#1pt<0.5pt\cellcolor{tablered}\else
\ifdim#1pt<1pt\cellcolor{tableyellow}\else
\cellcolor{tablegreen}\fi\fi
#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{raggedright}
    
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & EK1 & EK2-1 & EK2-2 & EK2-3 & EK3-1 & EK3-2 & EK4 & EK5-1\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
A & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
B & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
C & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
D & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
E & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
F & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
G & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
H & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
I & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
mean values & 0.89 & 1 & 0.94 & 1 & 1 & 0.72 & 0.94 & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\par\end{raggedright}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{raggedright}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & EK5-2 & EK5-3 & EK6-1 & EK6-2 & mean values\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
A & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & 0.75\tabularnewline
\hline 
B & \cellcolor{tablered} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & 0.82\tabularnewline
\hline 
C & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.79\tabularnewline
\hline 
D & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 0.96\tabularnewline
\hline 
E & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{0.5} & 0.83\tabularnewline
\hline 
F & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.92\tabularnewline
\hline 
G & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.96\tabularnewline
\hline 
H & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 0.92\tabularnewline
\hline 
I & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
mean values & 0.94 & 0.67 & 0.94 & 0.56 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\par\end{raggedright}
\centering{}\caption{example table}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You wrote, "I have tried to put them both into a centered `minipage` and within this minipage flush them to the left. But that doesn't seem to work." Not sure what you tried, as this approach works just fine for me. Do give `\centering\begin{minipage}{0.82\textwidth}` a try.

Comment: The two tables seem to be two halfes of one larger table. Why not use a single table with a total of 16 columns instead of splitting it up? If you reduce the font size to `\small` and at the same time adjust the value of `\tabcolsep`, the 16 column version of the table should fit into the available textwidth.

Comment: @Mico I forgot what went wrong when I tried this approach. Maybe I should have had a deeper look into it. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing both `tabular` environments in a single `minipage` is definitely the way to go.

I would also make sure that the data columns all have the same width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,margin=2cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,patterns,calc,matrix,arrows.meta}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,56,101}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{106,176,35}
\definecolor{tablegreen}{RGB}{224,239,212}
\definecolor{tableyellow}{RGB}{255,251,204}
\definecolor{tablered}{RGB}{252,212,209}
\usepackage{colortbl,dcolumn}
\def\zz#1{%
\ifdim#1pt<0.5pt\cellcolor{tablered}\else
\ifdim#1pt<1pt\cellcolor{tableyellow}\else
\cellcolor{tablegreen}\fi\fi
#1}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[colorlinks,
    pdfpagelabels,
    pdfstartview = FitH,
    bookmarksopen = true,
    bookmarksnumbered = true,
    hypertexnames = false,
    linkcolor = black,
    plainpages = false,
    citecolor = black] {hyperref}

\newlength\mylength
\settowidth\mylength{EK6-2}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
%\begin{raggedright}

\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.87\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{ |c| *{8}{wc{\mylength}|} }
\hline 
 & EK1 & EK2-1 & EK2-2 & EK2-3 & EK3-1 & EK3-2 & EK4 & EK5-1\\
\hline 
\hline 
A & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1}\\
\hline 
B & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\\
\hline 
C & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\\
\hline 
D & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\\
\hline 
E & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\\
\hline 
F & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\\
\hline 
G & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\\
\hline 
H & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\\
\hline 
I & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\\
\hline 
mean values & 0.89 & 1 & 0.94 & 1 & 1 & 0.72 & 0.94 & 1\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.5cm}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & EK5-2 & EK5-3 & EK6-1 & EK6-2 & mean values\\
\hline 
\hline 
A & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & 0.75\\
\hline 
B & \cellcolor{tablered} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & 0.82\\
\hline 
C & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.79\\
\hline 
D & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 0.96\\
\hline 
E & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{0.5} & 0.83\\
\hline 
F & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.92\\
\hline 
G & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.96\\
\hline 
H & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 0.92\\
\hline 
I & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 1\\
\hline 
mean values & 0.94 & 0.67 & 0.94 & 0.56 & \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\caption{example table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a wrapper `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  pdfpagelabels,
  pdfstartview = FitH,
  bookmarksopen = true,
  bookmarksnumbered = true,
  linkcolor = black,
  plainpages = false,
  hypertexnames = false,
  citecolor = black
]{hyperref}

\geometry{
  %verbose,
  tmargin=2cm,
  bmargin=2cm,
  lmargin=2cm,
  rmargin=2cm
}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,56,101}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{106,176,35}
\definecolor{tablegreen}{RGB}{224,239,212}
\definecolor{tableyellow}{RGB}{255,251,204}
\definecolor{tablered}{RGB}{252,212,209}

\newlength{\colwidth}

\newcommand\ccell[1]{%
  \ifdim#1pt<0.5pt\cellcolor{tablered}\else
  \ifdim#1pt<1pt\cellcolor{tableyellow}\else
  \cellcolor{tablegreen}\fi\fi
  #1%
}
\newcolumntype{K}{w{c}{\colwidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\settowidth{\colwidth}{EK0-0}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{8}{ K| }}
\hline 
 & EK1 & EK2-1 & EK2-2 & EK2-3 & EK3-1 & EK3-2 & EK4 & EK5-1\\
\hline 
\hline 
A & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & \ccell{1}\\
\hline 
B & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1}\\
\hline 
C & \ccell{0} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1}\\
\hline 
D & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1}\\
\hline 
E & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1}\\
\hline 
F & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1}\\
\hline 
G & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1}\\
\hline 
H & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1}\\
\hline 
I & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1}\\
\hline 
mean values & 0.89 & 1 & 0.94 & 1 & 1 & 0.72 & 0.94 & 1\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\\
\noalign{\vspace{0.5cm}}

\begin{tabular}{|c|*{4}{K|}c|}
\hline 
 & EK5-2 & EK5-3 & EK6-1 & EK6-2 & mean values\\
\hline 
\hline 
A & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0} & 0.75\\
\hline 
B & \cellcolor{tablered} & \ccell{0.5} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0} & 0.82\\
\hline 
C & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & 0.79\\
\hline 
D & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & 0.96\\
\hline 
E & \ccell{0.5} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & \ccell{0.5} & 0.83\\
\hline 
F & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & 0.92\\
\hline 
G & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{0.5} & 0.96\\
\hline 
H & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & 0.92\\
\hline 
I & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & \ccell{1} & 1\\
\hline 
mean values & 0.94 & 0.67 & 0.94 & 0.56 & \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{tabular}

\caption{example table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I changed `\zz` to a better name.

The trick is to use `\noalign{\vspace{0.5cm}}` in order to separate the two rows.

I also suggest how to get equal width columns.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer admittedly does not focus on how one could achieve the requested alignment, but focuses more on the underlying issue of how one could make sure the whole table fits into the available space without the need to cut it in half:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{tablegreen}{RGB}{224,239,212}
\definecolor{tableyellow}{RGB}{255,251,204}
\definecolor{tablered}{RGB}{252,212,209}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{%
\ifdim#1pt<0.5pt\cellcolor{tablered}\else
\ifdim#1pt<1pt\cellcolor{tableyellow}\else
\cellcolor{tablegreen}\fi\fi
#1}
\makeatother

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{\tabcolsep}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\tabcolsep}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\small 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.15pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|*{12}{0{wc{\widthof{EK3-1}}}|}c|}
\hline 
 & EK1 & EK2-1 & EK2-2 & EK2-3 & EK3-1 & EK3-2 & EK4 & EK5-1 & EK5-2 & EK5-3 & EK6-1 & EK6-2 & \makecell{mean\\ values}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
A & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & 0.75\tabularnewline
\hline 
B & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \cellcolor{tablered} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & 0.82\tabularnewline
\hline 
C & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.79\tabularnewline
\hline 
D & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 0.96\tabularnewline
\hline 
E & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{0.5} & 0.83\tabularnewline
\hline 
F & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.92\tabularnewline
\hline 
G & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}  & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.96\tabularnewline
\hline 
H & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 0.92\tabularnewline
\hline 
I & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
\makecell{mean\\ values} & 0.89 & 1 & 0.94 & 1 & 1 & 0.72 & 0.94 & 1 & 0.94 & 0.67 & 0.94 & 0.56 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{example table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

centered both using `\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}`
I placed `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` before each `\begin{tabular}`.

Look at my version of your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\usepackage[colorlinks,
pdfpagelabels,
pdfstartview = FitH,
bookmarksopen = true,
bookmarksnumbered = true,
linkcolor = black,
plainpages = false,
hypertexnames = false,
citecolor = black] {hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf,pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,patterns,calc,matrix,arrows.meta}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,56,101}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{106,176,35}
\definecolor{tablegreen}{RGB}{224,239,212}
\definecolor{tableyellow}{RGB}{255,251,204}
\definecolor{tablered}{RGB}{252,212,209}
\usepackage{colortbl,dcolumn}
\def\zz#1{%
\ifdim#1pt<0.5pt\cellcolor{tablered}\else
\ifdim#1pt<1pt\cellcolor{tableyellow}\else
\cellcolor{tablegreen}\fi\fi
#1}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
 \begin{center}   
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & EK1 & EK2-1 & EK2-2 & EK2-3 & EK3-1 & EK3-2 & EK4 & EK5-1\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
A & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
B & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
C & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
D & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
E & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
F & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
G & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
H & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
I & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1}\tabularnewline
\hline 
mean values & 0.89 & 1 & 0.94 & 1 & 1 & 0.72 & 0.94 & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 & EK5-2 & EK5-3 & EK6-1 & EK6-2 & mean values\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
A & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & 0.75\tabularnewline
\hline 
B & \cellcolor{tablered} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & 0.82\tabularnewline
\hline 
C & \zz{1} & \zz{0} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.79\tabularnewline
\hline 
D & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 0.96\tabularnewline
\hline 
E & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{0.5} & 0.83\tabularnewline
\hline 
F & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.92\tabularnewline
\hline 
G & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{0.5} & 0.96\tabularnewline
\hline 
H & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 0.92\tabularnewline
\hline 
I & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & \zz{1} & 1\tabularnewline
\hline 
mean values & 0.94 & 0.67 & 0.94 & 0.56 & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\centering{}\caption{example table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I also removed `raggedright`. Now your tables are both centered.

[image]

Comment: The OP doesn't want both `tabular` environments to be centered.

Comment: I am surprised, I have no problems to compile it and it works. I have centered each one of the tables individually.

Comment: I did *not* say that your code doesn't compile. Instead, I said that the layout doesn't satisfy the OP's stated objective.